# How to handle json response in jquery with multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, response

When I handle the response I get using jQuery ajax and if the response comes as

{"id":"11","name":"Steffy"}

I am able to handle it as 
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: "post",
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (resp) {
                     var id=resp.id, name=resp.name;
                }

But when I get a response like the below, I am unable to handle. Kindly guide me.

{"one":{"id":"11","name":"Steffy"},"two":{"id":"17","name":"Marc Smith"}}

I tried using resp.one.id but it does not work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: access it by resp["one"].id

Comment: you have a typo - use `resp.one.id` *not* `rep` - otherwise it should work.

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh, tried but not works. and thanks wahwahwah, I edited question. I am getting the response in firebug, but the code which I give after getting response do not work.

Comment: var row=jQuery("<div>").addClass("modal-header");
    row.append(jQuery("<button>").text("x").attr("data-dismiss", "modal").attr("aria-hidden", "true").addClass("close"));
    row.append(jQuery("<h4>").text(resp.one.name).addClass("modal-title"));
    jQuery("#show-modal-sent").append(row);

Comment: can you check the type of the responses?
is your response coming back as a correct json object?
what is the error when you call resp['one']? is it 'undefined'? or does it show the object?

Comment: @wahwahwah you are right. it was a typo error. I was appending data to #show-modal-sent which does not exist instead of #show-modal-send